# Can SQL Query activity can reference Send Logs in combination with System data views?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am aware that we can use either Filter and Query on a SEND LOG data extention to get out of the box tracking details.

However, can we use **SEND LOG** and **SYSTEM DATA VIEW** [example: _Open] as a combination while querying?

Comment: The answer is Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple: **Yes**.

It would be interesting to join Send logs and System Data Views to get data that is not accessible in Data views.

> Send logging gives you access to data not available via standard
>   tracking functions. You can specify how long that information remains
>   available depending on your data retention needs.
>
> Each data extension includes required fields with values used to
>   identify the send, subscriber, and other information. To keep
>   additional information in the send logging data extension, create a
>   column in the data extension to contain it. The column names in the
>   send logging data extension must match the attributes or field names
>   in the sendable data extensions to log values.

Reference:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_send_logging.htm&type=5